# Power Utility Function Inverse

Tags: utility

If power utility is $p = \frac{x^{1- \gamma} -1}{1 - \gamma}$ then is the inverse of the power utility function just  $\frac{1 - \gamma}{p^{1- \gamma} -1}$?

Comment: The inverse of the function $f(x)$ usually means the function $g$ such that $g(f(x))=f(g(x))=x$...

Comment: So what I have above is not the inverse for power utility?

Comment: I don't know what "power utility" is, and I don't know what it is you are trying to calculate, but you do not have the **inverse function** of the first function, no. But you might have what you need. I can't know that.

Comment: It would be better if you give the definition of `power utility`.

Comment: It's also called the isoelastic utility function does that help?

Comment: Do you want to compute the inverse function of $$p=\frac{x^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}$$?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know what the inverse function is.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $p= \frac{x^{1-\gamma}- 1}{1-\gamma}$ we find the inverse by solving for x-  Multiply both sides by $1-\gamma$:  $p(1-\gamma)= x^{1-\gamma}-1$.
Add 1 to both sides: $p(1-\gamma)+ 1= x^{1-\gamma}$.

Finally, take the $1-\gamma$ root of both sides:  $(p(1-\gamma)+ 1)^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma}}= x$.